# ID please and hardiness zone

Tags: identification, hardiness-zone

[image]

Please ID this succulent and its hardiness zone, I'd like to know if it can be left outdoor over winter in Zone 5 Canada. Both plants were planted at the same time 6 weeks ago with the inset picture grown indoor. Both are about 6 inches tall but as shown in the picture the one grown indoor is leggy but with shiny leaves. The one left outdoor in a shady location looks healthier and happier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the answer without even knowing the exact species and variety is a solid NO. These are desert plants.  I am glad the one on the left is in the shade out of doors.  You have to pull these plants back indoors BEFORE the temperature drops below 40!  If they were in the sun you would have to re acclimate them back into the indoor environment.  I take all my indoor plants out for the summer season under a roof or cover.  They get far more light that way, make more food to last the winter in low light.

Your plant on the window sill is in a pot with no drainage.  Or is there a hole in that pot?  Succulents, desert plants have shallow root systems. Those roots have to suck up water whenever the desert gets a rain and then they STORE that water.  Pots any deeper than 6 inches can be a concern if you water too deeply.

Your plant on the left looks as if it is in the sun.  Is it?  You had better start bringing it inside for an hour a day for 3 days, extending the time to half a day before bringing it in for the winter.  What are you doing for fertilizer, better yet what soil have you used in those pots?  I hope it was potting soil, not garden soil?  What are the temps at night?  I'd be bringing them in every night now anyway!

No these plants are not meant to be outdoors in Canada for the fall or winter and some of the spring!  Grins...

An aside, since these plants require so little water, please go find a bottled water without fluoride or better, find a friend who has well water and borrow some.  Tap water is awful stuff that we shouldn't be giving our dogs, cats, babies nor ourselves!

Comment: @J.Musser  You are more familiar with indoor succulent ID than me.

Comment: The closest I came for ID on your larger succulent is Echeveria could be a cross or hybrid.  You've got at least 4 other succulents in your grouping.  Be oh so stingy with water.  Do not soak the soil, only water the top inch of soil and only water when that soil is dry.  The worst thing people do for succulents is over water and using tap water and not using potting soil and not using a little bit of balanced fertilizer and not giving it enough light.  Hope this helps.  Look up Succulents and go to images.  Scroll through to find similar looking plants and then go to the page for information.

Comment: Thank you Stormy for all the tips. Pot of the indoor one has drainage holes. Soil used is for cactus, not fertilized yet. I've watered only once and that was after 4 weeks after repotting. Outdoor one, on the left, had not been fertilized yet. Temps are 50-60 at night.

Comment: @stormy: Why do you say "desert plants"? Succulents (like Sedum and Sempervivum) live also on cold places (just dry). But the colour of leaves doesn't seems to be adapt to sun desert (nor to mountain climate). So for the habit, I would bet some salt/wet environment (succulent: to store sweet water, but green without hairs and spikes and extended: wet)